# How i can deny data flowing over a established TCP connection but socket connection should remain in valid state.

Tags: c, linux, sockets, tcp, network-programming

I need a case where established TCP connection give some errors , like either sendto() failed or recieve() but socket connection should remain in place. 
   this way i want to check if in my application any data sending and recieving failes for one or twice , then how it will behave.
   Initially, i have tested it by harcoding these values but now i want to see it in real time scenario.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: even i am not sure if it possible or NOT ...

Comment: Tried using iptables in established connection but it evantully breaking the connection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can make send/receive act as what you exactly think, but there may be a workaround.

You can define a global flag, and setup a signal handler to change the flag value. Then in shell you can send the signal to your app to change the flag value. By judging the flag value, your can make your program enters the error test case in real time scenario:

The global flag and the signal handler:

```
int link_error = 0;

static void handler(int sig)
{
    link_error = 1;    /* indicating error happens */
}
```

In main() setup a signal, such as SIGUSR1(a macro with the value 10 in LINUX X86),

```
struct sigaction sa = {0};

sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
sa.sa_flags = 0;
sa.sa_handler = handler;

if(sigaction(SIGUSR1, &sa, NULL) == -1)
    return -1;
```

Then redefine the to be tested function such as send() to judging the flag value:

```
int send_test(...)
{
    /* Link error happens */
    if(link_error) { 
        link_error --; 
        return -1;
    }

    return send(...); 
}
```

When your program is running, you can do the test by kill -s 10 xxx(xxx is your program pid) at any time.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure I follow you but...

Try unplugging the network cable from the device you're talking to, not from the machine you're running your code on. It's one failure case. You could also write some test app for the other end that deliberately stalls or shuts down wr or rd only; changing the size of the tx & rx buffers for the socket will allow you to quickly fill them and see stalls as a result. You could probably also do other things like make your MTU very small, that usually tests a bunch of assumptions in code. You could also stuff something like [WanEm](http://wanem.sourceforge.net/) in the mix to stress your code.

There are a lot of failure cases in networking that need testing, there's no simple answer to this.

Answer (score 0):

If you get any error on a socket connection other than a read timeout, the connection is broken. It does not 'remain in place'. Ergo you cannot induce such a condition in your application. All you can do is hold up the sending end for long enough to induce read timeouts.